# Generating 100 balls at random position within restricted space (has radius and no overlapping)

Tags: algorithm, random, complexity-theory, big-o

For example, the restricted space is 100 x 100 x 100 big, and the radius of each ball is 5, I need to generate 100 of these balls at random position within this space and **no overlapping allowed**. I come up with two approaches:

1. Use srand and get 100 positions, then do a checking to delete balls that overlap each other ( check if the distance of the center of two balls are less than two times the radius), then generate another x balls (x is the number of balls deleted) and keep repeating the process until 100 balls don't overlap.
2. First divide the space into 100 cubes, and place each ball within its allocated cube using `srand`, this way they won't overlap at all.

I feel the first way is more proper in terms of random, but too time consuming and the second way is fast and easy but I'm not sure about the idea of random there. And this model is trying to simulate the position of molecules in the air. Maybe neither of these ways are good, please let me know if there's better way. Thanks in advance!

Edit: 
@Will provides me an option that's similar but much cleaner than my original first approach; every time when adding a new ball, check if it overlap with any existing ones, if it does, regenerate. The complexity is 1+2+3...+(n-1), which is about O(n^n). I still wonder if there's faster algorithm though.

Edit2:
Sorry 1+2+..n should be n^2

Comment: Second one.  What, you need that in an answer?  I'd rather have to derp less at the algorithm than be truly random.  Third option, drop a ball.  Then drop balls in the area not already covered.  If you can figure that algo out, you probably should have a masters.  I've got a derpsters, as I already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Will though I have some difficulty understanding the word `derp` (not a local speaker myself). I'm in undergrad now, just helping my friend's chemistry research. When you say masters, are you suggesting this is a very deep problem? I think your third option is actually great. Every time I generate a new ball, I check if it overlap with existings, if does, regenerate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For your edit, you suggest that the complexity of 1+2+3... + n-1 is O(n^n) but it is actually O(n^2).

Comment: @Arch1tect: "derp" is the sound that stupid makes, I guess... Anyhow, a trivial implementation of the third suggestion would probably result in a big cluster of balls rather than an even distribution.

Comment: You can limit the number of balls you need to check for overlap by dividing your space up into cubes of some size, say 5x5x5, then on creating each ball, find each cube it intersects and check if there is any ball in them that would intersect with it. If not, add it and add a hash from each cube it intersects to it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do an O((n + f) log n) algorithm, where f is the number of failed attempts. Essentially the issue with the time taking too long is finding which neighboring balls you overlap with. You can use an external data structure called a KD-tree to efficiently store the positions of the balls. Then you can look up through the KD-tree your "nearest" neighboring ball. This will take O(log n) time. Determine if they overlap, then add the ball to the space and to the KD-tree -- inserting is a O(log n) operation. In total n balls each taking O(log n) will be O(n log n), and accounting for failed attempts will be O((n+F)*log n). CGAL (computational geometric algorithms library) provides a nice KD-tree implementation. Here is a link to CGAL and a link to KD trees:

http://www.cgal.org/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

There are other structures like a K-D tree, but this would be the easiest to use for your case.

If you would like to avoid using a fancy data structure, you can compute a grid over the space. Insert each random ball from the entire space into its grid cell. Then when checking overlap you only need to check the balls in adjacent cells (assuming the ball size will not overlap more than one adjacency). This will not improve the overall time complexity, but is a common method in computer graphics to improve implementation time for neighbor finding routines.

Comment: In general, I don't think this will be an `O(n*log(n))` approach - it will be `O((n + F)*log(n))` where `F` is the number of failed insertions (due to  ball overlap). If ball positions are chosen at random, `F` can become very large `F >> O(n)`.

Comment: This is true, but in such a large space (volume of the ball is around 222 compared with total volume of space at 1000000), over 100 random balls the failed attempts will most likely be small. I'll edit my post accordingly, Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant the volume of a ball is 523.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of dividing the area into a 100 cubes, you could divide it into 8,000 5 by 5 cubes, and then place balls centered into 100 of those cubes. This way the balls are still placed randomly in the space but the can't overlap.
Edit: Also, for when checking if the balls overlap, you might want to think about using a data structure that would allow you to only check the balls that are closest to the ball you are checking. Checking all of them is wasteful because there's no chance of balls on totally different sides of the space overlap. I'm not too familiar with octrees but you might want to look into them, if you really want to optimize your code.

Comment: The radius is 5 so it should be 10 by 10 cubes of 1000, I think this is the best solution so far. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The volume of your spheres is about 1/1900th the volume of your space, so if you just pick random locations and check for overlap, you won't have to regenerate many. And if you really only need 100, using a fancy algorithm like Octrees to check for collisions would be a waste.

Of course as soon as you code it up, someone will ask you to do it for 10,000 spheres instead of 100, so everything I just said will be wrong.

I like Chris's suggestion of just putting them in randomly chosen cubes. Not the most realistic perhaps, but close and much simpler.